# List view with checkedTextView not working as intended

Tags: android, listview

I have this xml code for a list view:

```
<ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
            android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

This is the `list_selector` drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">

   <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

And the list_view has a checkedTextView as each item as follows:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/checkList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip" />
```

There are two problems with this setup.

1.) I can check the box next to each item but I cant uncheck it.
2.) Before I implemented the checkbox, the list selector makes the item go bluish when you select it, now when you select the item, the list_selector doesnt do anything, only the checkbox becomes ticked.

So is there anyway to be able to solve 1. and make it so as, I have to click just the checkbox to tick/untick it and when I click anywhere else within the listview item, list_selector comes into play?

EDIT: My custom adapter: Also, I have solved the marking/unmarking. It Works. The only problem now is 2.) as above!

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Contact> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context context;

    public ContactsAdapter(List<Contact> mData, Context context) {
        this.mData = mData;
        this.context = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        switch (context.getSharedPreferences("settings",
                HomeScreenActivity.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("displayChoice", -1)) {
        case 1:
            return mData.get(position).getLastName() + " "
                    + mData.get(position).getFirstName();
        case 2:
            return mData.get(position).getFirstName() + " "
                    + mData.get(position).getMobileNumber();
        case 3:
            return mData.get(position).getLastName() + " "
                    + mData.get(position).getMobileNumber();
        default:
            return mData.get(position).getFirstName() + " "
                    + mData.get(position).getLastName();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        CheckedTextView result;

        if (convertView == null) {
            result = (CheckedTextView) mInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.home_screen_contacts_view, parent, false);
        } else {
            result = (CheckedTextView) convertView;
        }

        final String contactRow = getItem(position);
        result.setText(contactRow);
        result.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector);

        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using a Custom Adapter for your listview or something else?

Comment: can you send your custom adapter class?

Comment: i think you should change `android:background="@drawable/list_selector"` to `android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"`

Comment: It didnt do anything different :(

Comment: I think you can setup your selector and checkedtext in getView method. But you must first creat a boolean array that hold checked items in it and set it into CheckTextView for every row in getView.